# Получить автора поста mvc

Tags: mvc, теория, псевдокод

В самой таблице у постов есть колонка `author` где хранится id пользователя-автора, но проблема в том, что я не понимаю как имя этого автора отобразить в представлении. Вернее, не понимаю кто эти данные должен получать.
Сама модель постов должна получать данные о пользователе или контроллер должен использовать две модели?

Comment: Используйте навигационные свойства

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем в псевдокоде, но расскажу вкратце и приближенно к тому, как это в PHP фреймворке Laravel устроено.

Построение взаимосвязи и нужные запросы инициируются в базовом классе модели. Если пытаешься обратиться к атрибуту `$somePost->author`, который является как раз взаимосвязью с другой моделью (В таблице есть столбец `author_id`, но отсутствует столбец `author`), то он выполняет запрос и получает связанную модель данных `Author::find($somePost->author_id)`, присоединяя её в нужный атрибут исходной модели, т.е. в `$somePost->author`. Сами исходники Laravel по этой части не смотрел, но процесс представляется таким образом. Опять же, следуя парадигме «худой контроллер — толстая модель» выходит, что эту связку действительно лучше держать на уровне моделей.

В Laravel пошли ещё дальше и добавили оптимизацию, для случаев, когда вам нужно вытащить посты с авторами для вывода, например, index страницы со всеми записями и их авторами. Добавлен eager loading, т.е. можно использовать что-то вроде:

```
Post::with('author')->all()
```

И загрузить таким образом сразу все посты с их авторами гораздо меньшим числом запросов, чем если будут идти обращения к БД для каждого поста.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно отделять доменные модели и модели отображения. Строить иерархию должны либо вы самостоятельно (SQL-JOIN двух таблиц и заполнение сущностей), либо ORM. Контроллер должен думать только о том, как взаимодействовать с интерфейсом, за запросы данных обычно отвечает слой доступа к данным (в примере это репозиторий):

Доменные сущности:

```
public class Author {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Post {
    int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Вью-модели:

```
public class PostViewModel {
    int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}
```

Сам контроллер (с маппингом моделей):

```
public class MyBlogController: Controller 
{
    private readonly IPostRepository _postRepository;
    public MyBlogController(IPostRepository postRepository) {
        _postRepository = postRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Post(int id) {
        var post = _postRepository.Get(id);
        if (post == null) return NotFound();

        var model = new PostViewModel{
            Id = post.Id,
            Title = post.Title,
            Content = post.Content,
            AuthorName = post.Author.Name
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

И репозиторий:

```
public interface IPostRepository
{
    Post Get(int id);
}

public class PostRepository: IPostRepository 
{
    protected readonly BlogDbContext _context;
    public PostRepository(BlogDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    Post Get(int id) {
        return _context.Posts.Include(x => x.Author);
    }
}
```